# ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name,NumberOfCores from Win32_Processor").Get() is very slow

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a program which gets cpu data. for some reason its very slow and takes up to 30sec to finish.

```
public static KeyValuePair<string, int> CPUData()
    {
        int coreCount = 0;
        string cpuName = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name,NumberOfCores from Win32_Processor").Get())
        {
            coreCount += int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString());
            cpuName = item["Name"].ToString();
        }
        return new KeyValuePair<string, int>(cpuName, coreCount);
    }
```

code that calls the function

```
public static void RunCommand(string response)
{
if (response.StartsWith("CMD"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(CommandHandler.ExecuteCommandAsAdmin(response.Substring(4)));
}
else if (response.StartsWith("sysInfo"))
{
    var data = CPUData();
    Console.WriteLine(data.Key + " " + data.Value);
}
else if (response.StartsWith("sysStatus"))
{
    
}
```

}

Comment: Main issue is `new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name,NumberOfCores from Win32_Processor")`, you're constructing a new instance every time, do it once and call `Get()` on that mos object instance in the loop.

Comment: @zaggler thanks but that didn't fix it. it's still slow on the first time I create it. it's better but still very slow and on the first time I run it, it takes about 20-30 sec to finish

Comment: I can't replicate the issue, mine is just under a second to run and return. How are you calling this routine?

Comment: @zaggler I'm calling the function if the user inputs sysinfo. in addition to that I debugged my code and I saw that my code get's stuck on the function rather than the line "foreach (var item in new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name,NumberOfCores from Win32_Processor").Get())" (this line is in the function that gets stuck)

Comment: Please update your post to include all code related to calling this function.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this wouldn't cause that delay either and I've not been able to replicate the long delay you are. How are you calling `RunCommand`?

Comment: from main(its a console application)